# Bash script to extract and re-compress contents from a list of ZIP files

Tags: bash, zip, command-line-interface, 7zip

I have about 500+ ZIP files which I need to re-compress using the best compression possible.

I looking at creating a script (one liner if possible) to extract the contents from each ZIP files (Some of them contain multiple files inside, but no more folders), pipe the output so that 7zip can re-compress them achieving a maximum compression ZIP file.
The script that I created below uses an intermediate stage by extracting into a temporary folder and then re-compressing, but I would like to skip that stage if possible.
Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

This is my script at the moment, which works OK. But I am sure there must be a more efficient manner to achieve this.

```
predir=$(pwd)   
for i in *.zip; do  
   dirname='echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1'  
   mkdir "$dirname"  
   7z x "$i" -o"$dirname"/ && rm "$i"  
   7za a -mm=Deflate -mfb=258 -mpass=15 -r "$i" "$predir"/"$dirname"/"*" && rm -rf  "$dirname"/   
done
```

Comment: I don't see how a piped-stream from zip to 7zip could maintain information about a directory structure and files inside that directory structure, but I might be wrong. To "transmit" converted files from one format to another, look for `-c` (character output, maybe pipe output) and then you need to find the corresponding argument for 7zip to read input from a pipe (or character stream). Find your smallest file, copy that, and use it for testing until you get it working. Update your Q with your best attempt to solve the problem, show error messages or other problems and people may help. GoodLuck

Comment: Also you need to read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, as your Q would be voted closed during the week (when more people are reading). Good luck.